# React бесконечные запросы на сервер в useefcte

Tags: reactjs, axios

У меня есть стейт в который я кладу тудушки, каждый раз когда захожу на страницу срабатывает fetch, когда меняю (например удалялю или добавляю таску) должен отправляться запрос, соответственно стейт с тудушками я положил в зависимости, но из-за этого получается, что внутри эффекта я перезаписываю стейт и этот же стейт у меня в зависимостях и соответственно постоянные запросы, как это переделать подскажите, пробовал в редакс сохранять, но естественно разницы нет, может стейт должен быть в другом компоненте?

```
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState<todoProps[]>([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user.id && isAuth) {
      fetchTodos(user.id).then((data) => setTodoList(data));
    }
  }, [todoList, user.id]);
```

Comment: Не вижу, чтобы вы в эффекте использовали `todoList`. значит он там и не нужен.

Comment: если его не использовать, то как мне перерендеривать страницу с новыми тудушками, когда они обновились, я делаю запрос, setTodoList обновляется, но чтобы страница перерендерилась, нужно чтобы в зависимостях был todoList, в таком случае при каждом обновлении todoList страница будет обновляется или может подскажите как мне это делвть, если не класть todoList в зависимости

Comment: Вам не нужна зависимость для `todoList` в`useEffect`, если стейт изменится, страница сама перерендерится

Answer (score 0):

Хук **useEffect** следит за изменениями, которые вы ему передаете в списке зависимостей.
В вашем коде получается многократный ре-рендер из-за того, что вы обновляете стейт и следите за обновлением этого же стейта.

Поэтому просто сделайте так

```js
const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState < todoProps[] > ([]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (user.id && isAuth) {
    fetchTodos(user.id).then((data) => setTodoList(data));
  }
}, [user.id]);
```

Если хотите удалить какие-то данные, то можно сделать так

```js
type todo = {
  id: string
}

const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState < todo[] > ([])

const onDelete = (delId: string) => {
  setTodoList((state) => state.filter(({
    id
  }) => id !== delId))
}
```

Так точно будет ре-рендер

Comment: я понимаю в чем ошибка и я это описал, типа в зависимости я кладу todoList, дальше вызываю эффект и в эфеекте обновляю эту же зависимость, получается все по кругу, но вопрос не в этом был, вопрос в том как сделать правильно, чтобы я вызывал fetchTodos и setTodoList после каждого изменения, если сделать так как вы описали выше, то при удалении тудушки, она будет удаляться в бд, но ожидаемого перерендеринга я не увижу, а увижу измененный список тудушек, только полсе обновления страницы и нового fetchTodos

Comment: А каким образом вы удаляете тудушки, что у вас не происходит ре-рендер?